# WD Passport Won't Mount

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, mount

My WD Passport won't mount. However, it turns on when plugged into my macbook and doesn't make any strange noises. It took a small fall (just a few inches and it was on my couch) and I'm very concerned about physical damage.

When I open up disk utility it shows the root 500 GB WD My Passport drive which seems to be OK when I verify it and repair it. However, the "External Hard Drive", the directory underneath the "500 GB WD My Passport drive" is grayed out. When I verify the External Hard Drive it says it needs to be rapaired. When I try and repair it it gives me the following message and does not seem to progress:

"Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required."

Is there hope for me recovering my data? I stupidly have important data on it that I don't have anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

As the disk had experienced physical shock/trauma, take it to a hard disk data recovery service. Check the classifieds in a newspaper or Craigslist for these outfits.